# Arabic Encoding in UFT-8 from Web Service

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I am trying to encode Arabic text from a Web service. Currently the values come as question marks (???).
I have read many blogs (even stackoverflow answers/links) but nothing seems to worked. 
Any idea of how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: has the font arabic characters?

Comment: What do mean the font? The characters are coming from a web service. Its a string of question marks

Comment: you have to Encode your InputStream to the proper Charset, somethimes depends on charset that's came from Native OS

Comment: Please be more specific and provide code samples (Java code, samples of the web service requests and responses). If you're consuming a web service, i.e. you've written a client for it, then you're more likely to _decode_ Arabic text (and not _encode_). Where exactly do you see the question marks (in the debugger, in a UI, in a saved XML file)? Are you using a specific library for consuming the web service?

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958556/reading-arabic-text-from-oracle-database-encoded-in-we8iso8859p1-using-java/34543337#34543337

Answer (score 0):

If you use dreamweaver's designer view and paste your Arabic text in design view you will get ascii characters in dreamweaver's code view which will work in any web browser.

Answer (score 0):

First, an important aside: *check* that the web service you are consuming sends you actual Arabic characters and not actual question marks. Check a network dump if you are not sure, and use wget/curl to perform a simple transaction; check the results.

If the raw data as sent by the WS is question marks, you have an uphill battle - try again and fiddle with the [Accept/Accept-Charset](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) headers. If all fail, it may be that the server itself isn't coded properly and there ain't much you can do after that...

Also, you're trying to *decode* the text, convert it from a byte representation to abstract characters.

Answer (score 0):

This has been the problem Sending `UTF-8` data from Android. Your code would work fine except that you will have to encode your `String` to `Base64` . At Server PHP you just decode `Base64` String back. It worked for me. I can share if you need the code.