# Reading Arabic text from Oracle database encoded in WE8ISO8859P1 using java

Tags: java, oracle, encoding, utf-8, arabic

I connect to Oracle database which has NLS_CHARACTERSET (WE8ISO8859P1) , which as far as I know cannot support storing Arabic text.

But Toad for Oracle can read Arabic from this database:

[image: Toad:]

However, I cannot read this using java code.

even I tried to get row of them in bytes using UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW

The result was "218,227,237,225,228,199,32,199,225,218,210,237,210,161,225,222,207,32,199,211,202,229,225,223,202,32,32,56,48,37,32,227,228,32,230,205,207,199,202,32,221,225,237,223,211,32,32,32"

In a test java class, I tried to create new String(new char[]{}) using the above mentioned bytes, with no luck to display Arabic characters.

Any help ? , thank you.

Comment: Would `new String(byteArray, "UTF-8")` help?

Comment: @npinti , unfortunately no, I tried with no luck.

Comment: Is it an NVARCHAR2 data type column?

Comment: @Wernfried No, it's VARCHAR2(1000)

Comment: those bytes don't seem to be valid utf-8: `11011010 11100011 11101101 11100001 11100100 11000111`... 11011010 should be followed by a 10xxxxxx byte.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by quite a few things:

1. Check the column type in database it should be `NVARCHAR` not `VARCHAR` (notice the **"N"** at the beginning of the word)
2. Try to put `charset=utf8` in the connection string
3. Convert the `byte[]` to string using UTF-8 encoding like this

   ```
   String arabicText = new String(byteArray, "UTF-8");
   ```